# data is not entering into mysql

Tags: php, mysql

i have written few codes to show time spent by users at site but when a users click on submit it should be stored in mysql but its not getting stored can you please tell where i have done mistake here is my code.

Comment: you mean to do an update, not an insert?

Comment: @ bob originally if it has 500 in that cell after users spend some time it will show 600 for example then it should be inserted or updated in mysql on submit please help.

Comment: @Sujit: Take a look at PDO (http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or MySQLi (http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) please

Comment: @Charlie Somerville: how could PDO help to person, who cannot compose valid query? Does PDO have built-in AI that rewrites everything into correct queries?

Comment: @ZERKMS PLEASE HELP TO SOLVE THE PROBLEM

Comment: @Sujit Tiwari: there is already great answer posted by cwallenpoole. If you cannot get it - you need to learn SQL basics.

Comment: @zerkms: The perfect time to introduce someone to PDO/MySQLi is when they are a beginner. `ext/mysql` is deprecated and is simply terrible.

Comment: @Charlie Somerville: currently all he does most of the time is just looking for something similar and adapting it for his needs. The last thing he cares about is code quality or backward compatibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an UPDATE instead of an insert.

```
$dtime = getChangeInTime(); // this is the change in time from the last update
mysql_query( "UPDATE jcow_accounts SET `TIME_SPENT` = `TIME_SPENT` + $dtime ". 
                 " where id='{$client['id']}'" );
```

Comment: i have already the codes for time update so i dont need to update or add the present time from the previous time. i tried your codes its not working . i have tried $Time = $row['Time_Spent'];
mysql_query( "UPDATE jcow_accounts SET `Time_Spent` = `$Time`  ". 
                 " where id='{$client['id']}'" );

Comment: @zerkms i know sql and have done written several codes but this time i dont know where its going wrong. if you can help me to get it working i will be very happy

Comment: @Sujit Tiwari: unfortunately you don't know sql at all. `INSERT` **cannot** be used with `WHERE`. @cwallenpoole's answer is perfectly valid. So you need to rewrite your query to `UPDATE` in the way he proposed, without additional `SELECT` at all

Answer (score 3):

Your query seems to be wrong.

Either use `INSERT` without `WHERE` if you want to insert a new record. If however you want to update an already present record, use `UPDATE` instead of `INSERT`.

And it is always a good idea to check whether a query was successful:

```
if (mysql_query ("insert into jcow_accounts(Time_Spent) values ('{$Time}') where uid='{$client['id']}'  ") === FALSE) {
    echo 'MySQL error: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try

```
insert INTO `jcow_accounts` (`Time_Spent`) VALUES ('{$Time}') where uid='{$client['id']}' WHERE `uid` = '{$client['id']}'
```

Are you sure the uid is in the DB? try running it without the WHERE...

Comment: Reply bellow is actually right, not sure how I managed to overlook that

Comment: There is no any reserved keyword in the query. Btw, you've made the query more incorrect by adding another WHERE

Comment: @saulius if i will run without uid it will not go to particualr users . UID is for the owner of that account so i need to give it . what code you have given same code i am using but i have not tried UPDATE . please guide how to do . its not getting stored in mysql

Comment: So are you trying to update the user's time spent on the site? code for that would be UPDATE jcow_accounts SET Time_Spent = '{$Time}' WHERE uid = '{$client['id']}'

Comment: @SAULIUS I TRIED YOUR CODE BUT ITS NOT WORKING